# Detecting user-activity on mac os x

Tags: c, macos, iokit, user-activity

I use the function "IOPMSchedulePowerEvent" to schedule Sleep or Wake-Events and registered my daemon with "IORegisterForSystemPower" to receive power-state-changes. Everything works fine!

When system going sleep and later waking up at scheduled time, my daemon do some work, and after it system should going sleep again.

Now my questions:

1. How can i detect, if the system was awaked by user or by the scheduled time?
2. How can i detect, if a user currently working with the system, so the daemon have not to put it in sleep-mode???

Thanks
Nobik

Answer (score 6):

There's an easy way to detect various forms of user interaction: Using [`CGEventSourceCounterForEventType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1408794-cgeventsourcecounterforeventtype) you can query the number of keyboard presses or mouse moves since boot time. By doing this at regular intervals and comparing the counts, you can detect interaction.

Comment: This is a good idea, thanks, but i'm searching for an easier way to do this.
Windows give me the "IsSystemResumeAutomatic-Function", to get the information. Is there a comparable function for mac?