# Detect Idle Time in Multi-Device Application on OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I need to detect Idle Time, Time Since the user has input anything into their machine, I've made this application before for windows only and this function worked brilliantly :-

```
function IdleTime: DWord;
var
  LastInput: TLastInputInfo;
begin
  LastInput.cbSize := SizeOf(TLastInputInfo);
  GetLastInputInfo(LastInput);
  Result := (GetTickCount - LastInput.dwTime) DIV 1000;
end;
```

However, this function doesn't work on Multi-Device Application(as far as I can tell). I've messed around with this for a while now and done some severe googling to no avail.

The target OS is OS X and Windows.

Comment: `GetLastInputInfo` works across the entire user session - is this what you are looking for?  Not just your application, but any user input to any application on the device?

Comment: If yes, I don't think FMX has anything ready-built for this.  For OSX/Win I would expect you to need to do this conditionally using WinAPI for the latter and probably `ioreg` for OSX.  A shell script example here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17966890/327083

Comment: J, Exactly, I want to detect when someone has walked away from their machine for X amount of time, with no input during that time. I'll have a look into that, thanks :)

Comment: Removed *pascal* tag. Nnless you can tell us what plain old Pascal compiler you're using that does multi-device applications, Delphi or C++ Builder would be the only applicable language tags here. Please don't just add random tags because they have familiar words in them; tags here have specific meanings. If you're not sure if the tag applies, read it's description. If you're still not absolutely sure it applies, don't use it.

Comment: Obviously your Delphi version is not 2010 if you're targeting osx. I've updated the tag to Delphi Seattle. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Ken, Johan, Sorry for the mistakes, First time posting and all, Thanks for the corrections, that was correct, I am using 10 Seattle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `GetLastInputInfo` on OSX is `CGEventSourceCounterForEventType`.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventSourceCounterForEventType

See here: [Detecting user-activity on mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922846/detecting-user-activity-on-mac-os-x)

The API interface for this call is in: `Macapi.CoreGraphics`
So you'll need to add that unit to your uses clause.

If you're not familair with OSX programming under Delphi, have a look at:https://delphihaven.wordpress.com

Comment: Brilliant, Exactly what I was looking for, Marking this as Correct answer, Thanks to everyone else for their input too.